# Cassandra isolation model

Tags: cassandra

I have a use case for Cassandra where I need to store multiple rows of data, which will belong to different customers. I'm new to Cassandra and I need to provide a permissions model where only one customer is accessible at once from a base permissions role but all could be accessible from a 'supervisor' role. Essentially every time a query is made, one customer cannot see another customer's data, except for when the query is made from a supervisor. We have to enforce a security as a design approach.

The data could look like this:

```
-----------------------------------------
| id  | customer name | data column1... |
-----------------------------------------
| 0   | customer1     | 3               |
-----------------------------------------
| 1   | customer2     | 23              |
-----------------------------------------
| 2   | customer3     | 33              |
-----------------------------------------
| 3   | customer3     | 32              |
-----------------------------------------
```

Is something like this easily doable with Cassandra?

Comment: Why not spin up two instances of Cassandra per tenant? Hardware is cheap nowadays

Comment: The use case asks for a single database, I looked into keyspaces earlier but that didn't seem to fit. The cassandra dbs have to be containerized (not my call).

Answer (score 1):

The way you have modeled this is a perfectly good way to do multi-tenant. This is how UserGrid models multiple tenants and is used in several large scale applications.

Couple of drawbacks to be up-front:

- Doesn't help with a "noisy neighbor" problem and unequal tenants
- Application code has to manage the tenant security

Comment: Can you elaborate on this a bit? This is a project to be used as a demo, it won't be used in a production environment. The main requirement I have is to ensure that only one tenant's data is accessible at once for a base role and that a superuser role could access all tenant data. Is it possible to enforce a security like this using Cassandra's tooling?

Comment: There isn't anything like row level security built into Cassandra... yet. It is something that I think is coming. Until then it is application based security. The best way I've seen to manage this is with access methods exposed to user facing parts of the application. Ex getUser(username, tenant) which is the only way to get user data.